# Non-english TV/Movies

Tags: discussion

Are questions about non-English TV & Movies on topic on this website?  Does the community have sufficient familiarity with foreign films/tv to justify asking these sorts of questions here?

Answer (score 9):

Yes they are on-topic, but the questions themselves have to be asked and answered in English.

By 'justify' I think you mean 'will I get good answers about non-English language movies and TV'?  By our very nature we are English language centric as a community - but we do have a reasonably significant contingent from non-English speaking regions of the world, and many for whom English is their second language.  Already we have a small number of questions about (non-British/Irish) European and Indian movies.  We even have an Indian Movies specific chat room.

I suggest you ask and find out.