# Is it appropriate to ask about movie plot points which I don't understand because the movie is in Chinese?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm studying the Chinese movie 妖猫转 ([Legend of the Demon Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Demon_Cat)) in an effort to improve my Chinese.  There's major plot points I don't understand because my Chinese is insufficient.  This particular movie also involves Chinese history and Chinese poetry.

While it seems foreign-language films are on-topic (see [Non-english TV/Movies](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/non-english-tv-movies)), I'm worried that a question about these plot points will be poorly received due to being overly simple ("improve your Chinese", "this was explained in the movie", "watch the movie again", etc.).  Basically, I would be only asking the question because my Chinese is not that great.  But maybe this is okay.

Hence...

**Question**: Is it appropriate to ask about movie plot points which I don't understand because the movie is in Chinese?

Such questions don't seem appropriate for [Chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/), as they're not about the Chinese language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More questions about the plot are explained in the movie. In fact, unless there is additional material, the only source for answers would be the movie itself. It's perfectly fine to ask questions about this. Especially if it is about the plot specifically.

We do have a rule about trivia questions, which is aimed at questions that are unrelated to the plot in such a way that they would only be interesting in trivia. This doesn't sound like that's the case.

**One note though**, while I don't think the question will be necessarily poorly received, it might be that the movie you intend to ask about is so obscure (Not frequently viewed by our users) that it might go without an answer. This shouldn't stop you from asking the question in the first place, but it is something to be aware of.